# Why NameError has NameError in ancestors on the second (not first) position?

Tags: ruby

While I've tried to fully understand difference between NoMethodError and NameError I've found that NameError is not on 0 position in ancestors. Is it some magic of `DidYouMean`?

```
[1] pry(main)> NameError.ancestors
=> [DidYouMean::Correctable,
 NameError,
 StandardError,
 Exception,
 ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Blamable,
 ActiveSupport::ToJsonWithActiveSupportEncoder,
 Object,
 ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable,
 PP::ObjectMixin,
 Nori::CoreExt::Object,
 JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object,
 ActiveSupport::Tryable,
 Kernel,
 BasicObject]
```

BTW: for someone who doesn't know difference between `NoMethodError` and `NameError`. `NameError` raised when you try to access something that can be a local variable for example

```
(pry)> foo # this can be both - local variable or method => NameError
(pry)> Object.foo # this is 100% method => NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it some magic of DidYouMean?

Nope, just regular ruby. This is what happens when you [use `prepend`](https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean/blob/db21b80d54f848df2fbf44d304046cf4000a9748/lib/did_you_mean.rb#L95-L96).

```
NameError.prepend DidYouMean::Correctable
KeyError.prepend DidYouMean::Correctable
```